# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14 error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I have added appcompat v7 library revision 22.2.0 to my project.I have replaced it's support v4 jar as it was not supporting viewpager (I am not using any other support v4 jar in this project).Now when I am Compiling the project,build is getting crashed due to this error.

Stack Trace :

```
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111): Process: com.ok.play, PID: 12111
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at com.ok.play.PayUImplementation.onCreate(PayUImplementation.java:58)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
11-17 10:42:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(12111):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Manifests's code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ok.play"
    android:versionCode="16"
    android:versionName="1.0.16" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.shopclues.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.ok.play.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ok.play.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.TELEPHONY"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.ok.play.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.CODConfirmation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
         <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.PayUImplementation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/app_id" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.CategoryTabs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.AddressDetail"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.UserProfile"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.OrderHistory"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.EditProfile"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.OrderDetail"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.DashBoardScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.ProductDetailScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.BrowseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.CategoryList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.ProductListScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.Registration"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.ChooseAddress"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.CreateNewAddress"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.CartProductList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.SubCategoryList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.ReviewOrderAndPay"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.ShoppingList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.ShoppingListDetailScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.Pramotion"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ok.play.PayumoneyWebview"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.payUMoney.sdk.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.payUMoney.sdk.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.payUMoney.sdk.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.payUMoney.sdk.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />



        <service android:name="com.ok.play.api.ConnectionService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.ok.play" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.ok.play.GCMIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="disable_web_view_back"
            android:value="true" />
        <!--
        <meta-data android:name="payu_merchant_id" android:value="gtKFFx"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="payu_merchant_salt"
            android:value="eCwWELxi" />
        -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio..??

Comment: check if in your project *properties > order and export* tab whether your jar is **ticked** or not

Comment: No, I am using eclipse.

Comment: You need to mark your project as an Android library project. Go to Project => Properties =>Android and checked the "is library".

Comment: post your manifests code ?

Comment: @Harshad Done.Plz check now.

Comment: @AmitBasliyal checked "is library" . Still getting error.

Comment: is there same error..

Comment: remove your unnecessary imports